# Multiple gulp sources and destinations

Tags: javascript, typescript, gulp, mocha.js

I am trying to have following directory structure

`-- src
     |__ app
          |__ x.ts
     |__ test
          |__ y.ts
-- build
     |__ app
          |__ js
     |__ test
          |__ js`

I want that on "gulp compile", I have my generated js files inside build/app and build/test. i.e. I have multiple sources and multiple destination.
I dont want to create a new gulp target for test one. Following are two various methods which I am trying to accomplish the task

```
gulp.task('compile', function () {
    //path to src/app typescript files
    var app_js = gulp.src('./src/app/**/*.ts')
        .pipe(tsc(tsProject))
    //path to src/test typescript files
    var test_js = gulp.src('./src/test/**/*.ts')
        .pipe(tsc(tsProject));
    return merge([
        app_js.js.pipe(gulp.dest('./build/src/app/')),
        test_js.js.pipe(gulp.dest('./build/src/test/'))
    ]);
});

gulp.task('bundle', function () {
    var paths = [
        { src: './src/app/**/*.ts', dest: './build/src/app/' },
        { src: './src/test/**/*.ts', dest: './build/src/test/' }
    ];
    var tasks = paths.map(function (path) {
        return gulp.src(path.src).pipe(tsc(tsProject)).pipe(gulp.dest(path.dest));
    })
    return merge(tasks);
});
```

However, every time, I run "gulp compile" or "gulp bundle", I hit following issues

> events.js:141
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>   ^Error: stream.push() after EOF
>       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:132:15)

Can somebody tell me that what am I doing wrong here?
NOTE: I tried using both merge-stream and merge2 packages.

Answer (score 1):

Ower! Thanks for your prompt response.

I end up with following solution

```
gulp.task('compile', function () {
    return gulp.src(['src/**/*.ts'] )
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(tsc(tsProject))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same project structure in one of my projects and I use the following for the build task:

```
var tsProject = tsc.createProject({
  removeComments : false,
  noImplicitAny : false,
  target : "ES5",
  module : "commonjs",
  declarationFiles : false
});

gulp.task("build-source", function() {
  return gulp.src(__dirname + "/source/**/**.ts")
             .pipe(tsc(tsProject))
             .js.pipe(gulp.dest(__dirname + "/build/source/"));
});

var tsTestProject = tsc.createProject({
  removeComments : false,
  noImplicitAny : false,
  target : "ES5",
  module : "commonjs",
  declarationFiles : false
});

gulp.task("build-test", function() {
  return gulp.src(__dirname + "/test/*.test.ts")
             .pipe(tsc(tsTestProject))
             .js.pipe(gulp.dest(__dirname + "/build/test/"));
});

gulp.task("build", function(cb) {
  runSequence("lint", "build-source", "build-test", cb);
});
```

I'm using two separated tasks because using one `tsProject` object with multiple sources and multiple destinations can lead to unexpected behavior.

> You must create the project outside of the task. You can't use the same project in multiple tasks. Instead, create multiple projects or use a single task to compile your sources. - [Source](https://github.com/ivogabe/gulp-typescript#incremental-compilation)

I also use the following for the bundle task:

```
gulp.task("bundle-source", function () {
  var b = browserify({
    standalone : 'inversify',
    entries: __dirname + "/build/source/inversify.js",
    debug: true
  });

  return b.bundle()
    .pipe(source("inversify.js"))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(__dirname + "/bundled/source/"));
});

gulp.task("bundle-test", function () {
  var b = browserify({
    entries: __dirname + "/build/test/inversify.test.js",
    debug: true
  });

  return b.bundle()
    .pipe(source("inversify.test.js"))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(__dirname + "/bundled/test/"));
});

gulp.task("bundle", function(cb) {
  runSequence("build", "bundle-source", "bundle-test", "document", cb);
});
```

My entire build script is available [here](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/blob/master/gulpfile.js). Hope it helps!